# Remove newline while while splitting file using awk

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file with 190 records and would like to split it to 190 individual files.
The problem I am facing is that after I split it to 190 individual files, a newline is added at the end of every file.

Each line has the word "NOTE" in it.

I am using the awk command

```
    awk '{if ($0 ~ /NOTE/) a++} {printf >> "file"a}' OrgFile.txt
```

Below is a sample of how my Orgfile.txt with 190 records looks

```
    2014-09-04-22.13.12.000000000000000912345678  NOTE  123456   123456
    2014-08-04-23.22.12.000000000000000912345678  NOTE  123456   123456
    2014-07-04-07.07.12.000000000000000912345678  NOTE  123456   123456
    .....
```

How can I still use this command to create these new individual files from the Orgfile but without a newline in them.

If anyone knows how to do this better it would also be great

Thanks

Comment: The command does *not* add a newline to the file. Open it in a hex editor to see.

Comment: It does, that is why i am asking this question

Comment: did you opened it in a hex editor?

Comment: yes i did and the last 1 byte is a 0A

Comment: The posted command will simply not work at all, itll produce a syntax error since `printf` requires an argument. Post the script you are REALLY using if you want us to help you debug it.

Comment: @EdMorton Sure, I just outputted `$0` and piped to `hexdump`. Result: No linefeed..

Comment: @hek2mgl my point is that the posted script won't execute as it contains a syntax error since you can't call `printf` with no arguments. So either the OP is calling print with no args which would add a newline or he's calling printf with args and depending on what formatting arg he's using it may or may not be adding a newline. We just need the OP to tell us what command he's really executing before we can start trying to help him debug whatever that command is.

Comment: @EdMorton Ok, got it

Answer (score 0):

I solve it using `print` instead of `printf`. I also made some changes in your script assuming that each line goes to a new file:

```
awk '$0 ~ /NOTE/ {print $0 > "file"(++a);}' OrgFile.txt
```

CHANGES: the pattern is out of the body (not using an if statement). Your post-increment can be done in the same print statement using a pre-increment.

And let me know if I misunderstood, but in your case, if a line does not contain the word "NOTE" it is appended to the last file you wrote because your print code is in another block that is always executed (even if this line does not contain the word "NOTE"). In my code, a line is written to a file only if it contains the word "NOTE", but you can change the code if I am wrong about your semantic ;-)